# when i set toolbar height is 50dp,but menu not center vertical in the toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

when i set toolbar height is 50dp,but menu not center vertical  in the toolbar

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can try to custom the menu button

Answer (score 0):

/** Try this it will work for you **/

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="@color/toolbar_bg_color">
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Back"
        android:gravity="end|center"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I believe the question is about the menu item not being aligned center vertically and not about the title text!

Comment: she is talking about the plus button which you can see it on the right corner

Comment: yea  plus button is an menu,but it not center vertical in the toolbar

Comment: @AmitRanjanStill, I don't see how this will help align the menu item center vertically. Please explain it in the answer if I am mistaken

Comment: actually she want the title on the toolbar should center allign with the plus button ,but when she is setting the height to 50dp then plus button is coming some what down with respect to her title.